# How can I add custom filter to a wordpress blog?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Im using simple fields in a wordpress site, so users can "tag" diferents post in admin.

Now, in the frontend view, I want to show a dropdown with the different options (distinct tags) that are avaible, so user can filter the post.

I know I need to modify some php code, and I found the exactly file where I need to touch, but I don't know even where to start.

My question is if I can add some custom php code, calling a mysql query and then add that recordset to fill the dropdown, or there is an more easy way to do this?

Any idea?

Comment: You got this downvote because your lowercase "i"-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) function in WordPress.

Since your question is too broad I just provide you with some examples that could help to get you started. First, add a function similar to the one below in your `functions.php` file,

```
function add_custom_tags($tags) {

    /** you can do a query to get these tags from database */
    $extra_tags = array(
        'tag1',
        'tag2',
        'tag3'
    );

    $tags = array_merge($extra_tags, $tags);
    return $tags;
}
add_filter('dropdown_tags', 'add_custom_tags');
```

where, `dropdown_tags` is the name of the filter and `add_custom_tags` is the function to be run when the filter is applied.

Then, you can use this filter in your dropdown function like this,

```
if(has_filter('dropdown_tags')) {
    $tags = apply_filters('dropdown_tags', $tags);
}
```

where `$tags` are current fields in your dropdown.

You can find good examples for `add_filter` function [here](https://pippinsplugins.com/a-quick-introduction-to-using-filters/).

Comment: thanks ! What i finally did was to add some custom php to the widget.php file, and then create my own <select> element. The weird part, is to filter the elements once loaded the DOM, because this template uses a UiKit library , dynamic grid, and it was super hard to understand how it worked. So i ended again, using custom js code over the page. Very messy solution, but it works!! I dont like this kind of code, but it really needed to work...